# Facebook status update with a photo (Without creating an Album)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ios4

I am using Facebook SDK in my iphone app. I am able to upload a photo with a caption.
*I follow this example: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/*

This is how I do it

```
- (IBAction) btnPostPress:(id) sender {

//[self.txtCaption resignFirstResponder];

//we will release this object when it is finished posting
FBFeedPost *post = [[FBFeedPost alloc] initWithPhoto:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] name:@"testing @ work"];
[post setCaption:@"Test"];
[post publishPostWithDelegate:self];

IFNNotificationDisplay *display = [[IFNNotificationDisplay alloc] init];
display.type = NotificationDisplayTypeLoading;
display.tag = NOTIFICATION_DISPLAY_TAG;
[display setNotificationText:@"Posting Photo..."];
[display displayInView:self.view atCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-100.0) withInterval:0.0];
[display release];
```

}

But the problem is, **When I upload more than 3,4 photos, it automatically create an Album with my application name.** Here on then photos upload to that album (**NOT LIKE Status update**)

But I want **every photo to post on the wall individually. Eg: if I upload 5 photos, then there should be 5 status updates with particular photo**.